# how to execute rake tasks using whenever gem, in amazon aws server in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rake-task

iam using whenever gem to execute a rake task, in my rails application. in development environment everything is working fine this is the following code.

```
 set :environment, "development"
 set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}

 every :day, :at => '12:10pm' do
  runner "Employee.assign_shift_policies"
 end
```

and in terminal to create a crontab and to run that cron tab file by using whenever gem iam running the following commands.

```
 whenever
 whenever -w
```

and the tasks are executing correctly. and the output of these rake tasks is appending to the following log files properly.

```
 log/cron_error_log.log
 log/cron_log.log
```

in development everthing is working fine. how to run these background jobs in amazon aws beanstalk server, means how to execute these `whenever` and `whenever -w` commands in amazon aws server to generate crontab and to execute those jobs in aws server by using elastic beanstalk?

now, i am using whenever-elasticbeanstalk gem. i am getting the following error in `eb-activity.log` file.

```
Command execution failed: Activity failed. (ElasticBeanstalk::ActivityFatalError)
caused by: /var/app/ondeck/vendor/bundle/gems/whenever-elasticbeanstalk-1.1.6/bin/create_cron_leader:10:in `join': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
  from /var/app/ondeck/vendor/bundle/gems/whenever-elasticbeanstalk-1.1.6/bin/create_cron_leader:10:in `<top (required)>'
  from /var/app/ondeck/vendor/bundle/bin/create_cron_leader:23:in `load'
  from /var/app/ondeck/vendor/bundle/bin/create_cron_leader:23:in `<main>'
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a gem that doing exactly what you need:

https://github.com/dignoe/whenever-elasticbeanstalk

Comment: but this gem is not the updated one. is there any alternate for this?